# Convert upcast pointer to base object that calls derived virtual

Tags: c++

I have two classes, one derived from the other. I want a function that returns an object (not pointer or reference) of the base class that calls the derived virtual function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void print() { cout << "Base" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void print() { cout << "Derived" << endl; }
};

Base go()
{
    Derived *derived = new Derived();

    Base *base = derived;
    base->print();

    // (*base).print(); // prints "Derived" !
    // Base base2 = (*base);
    // base2.print(); // prints "Base" !

    return *base;
}

int main()
{
    Base base = go();
    base.print();
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out

```
Derived
Base
```

So in the `go()` function I managed to convert to `Base` and the print works. But when I return the object the print is using the base function!

I know this can work if you return a pointer or a reference but I really need to return an object. Is this possible? Why does my code not work?

As you can see, I've commented out code in `go()` that de-references the upcast pointer. Strangely, it prints correctly! And if I do a conversion to an object, it doesn't!

Any insight into why this is all happening would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "but I really need to return an object".... why?

Comment: @tinkertime I'm eventually going to be overloading the assignment operator and that doesn't work with pointers / references... especially if you're trying to assign something like a float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return an actual object (and not a refernce or a pointer) it calls its copy ctor. In this case you return a Base class, so it calls its copy constructor and creates a **new** Base class object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base & base) { std::cout << "COPY BASE" << std::endl; }
    virtual void print() { cout << "Base" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(const Derived & derived) { std::cout << "COPY DERIVED" << std::endl; }
    void print() { cout << "Derived" << endl; }
};

Base go()
{
Derived *derived = new Derived();

Base *base = derived;
base->print();

// (*base).print(); // prints "Derived" !
// Base base2 = (*base);
// base2.print(); // prints "Base" !

return *base;
}

int main()
{
    Base base = go();
    base.print();
    return 0;
}
```

In this case the output will be:
Derived,
COPY BASE,
Base

Comment: I never understood that returning an object calls the copy constructor

Answer (score 1):

By returning the `base` object itself, you're dropping any reference to it having started off as `derived` and subsequently upcasted (and copied).

So effectively, what you're after will not work.

---

If you really "need this to return an object", I recommend a thin wrapper

```
struct karls_return_object {
    // ... stuff ...

    Base *b;
};
```

Comment: I see. Won't work for my purposes, but interesting to think about. Thanks